# Fantasy book about a boy with a set of 7 apparitions, one of which is very loyal and another has a jackal head

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember reading this young adult book about a decade ago. It's about this boy whose uncle dies and he inherits this tome, which I believe is called 'the book of seven'. It contains 7 apparitions (they had a name that I do not know), one of which is very loyal and another has a jackal head.

His uncles used them to make a living of investigating 'real' haunted houses on TV. The jackal apparition possesses him in the first book. He also meets this girl at his school.

In the third book (I believe there are only three) he breaks the book and basically becomes a god, where he shortens the River Styx.

Comment: Can you recall what sort of time period its set in?

Comment: @AlexRobinson modern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be the Host series by Leo Hunt? The three books in the series are *13 Days of Midnight*, *8 Rivers of Shadow* and *7 Trees of Stone* (published in 2015, 2016 and 2017 respectively).

There's a book with eight spirits rather than seven, and a dead father rather than a dead uncle, but otherwise it looks fairly close to your description.

According to [this review](https://www.washingtonindependentreviewofbooks.com/index.php/bookreview/13-days-of-midnight), the protagonist's father was 'the host of a famous paranormal TV show'.

A blurb for the first book from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/175555-13-days-of-midnight):

> When Luke Manchett’s estranged father dies unexpectedly, he leaves his son a dark inheritance: a Host of eight unique, powerful, and restless spirits. Unfortunately, Luke has no clue how to manage them, which the ghosts figure out pretty quickly. Armed with only his father’s indecipherable notes and a locked copy of The Book of Eight, Luke struggles to adapt to his new role as a necromancer. Meanwhile, the increasingly belligerent Host mutinies, possesses Luke’s mother, and forces him out of his own house.
>
> Halloween, the night when ghosts reach the height of their power, is
> fast approaching, and Luke knows his Host is planning something far
> more trick than treat. With the help of school outcast Elza Moss, who
> knows a bit about ghosts herself, Luke has just thirteen days to
> uncover the closely guarded secrets of black magic and send his
> unquiet spirits to their eternal rest.

Comment: This is exactly it, Thank you!!